# Illegal unit of measure(pt inserted) in BMVC paper template

Tags: mactex, overleaf

While I open a paper template in overleaf, there comes a Illegal unit of measure(pt inserted) and it won't disappear whether I change the LaTeX Engine. But the same code runs well while I build it in mactex. I also tried the highest rank solution of a similar problem in [Illegal unit of measure(pt inserted)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49098/illegal-unit-of-measurept-inserted), which still does not help. I'm confused now.
template link in overleaf: https://www.overleaf.com/read/yqkvhdgwknjs

Comment: Hello, please include a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) in the code. Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: I've changed your Overleaf project's read-and-edit URL to a read-only URL in the question, as otherwise your project will be directly editable by others—which you may not want!

Comment: Thank you for remind me! It has already changed so that I covered with a new one.

Answer (score 9):

*(Disclaimer: I'm a support personnel at Overleaf.)*

I got the same error while compiling your project on MacTeX 2016. The error is caused by line 657 of the `bmvc2k.cls` file:

```
\put(\LenToUnit{\textwidth\kern3pt},\LenToUnit{-\bmv@ruleroffset}){%right ruler
```

Changing it to

```
\put(\LenToUnit{\dimexpr\textwidth+3pt},\LenToUnit{-\bmv@ruleroffset}){%right ruler
```

solves the problem.

It may be worthwhile to feedback to the organiser/publisher about this so that they can update their template? A similar issue seemed to have been around for a while: [EveryShipout errors when using TikZ with conference style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76314/everyshipout-errors-when-using-tikz-with-conference-style)

Comment: Thank you for your solution! After modifying as you said. The previous problem has been solved. But another problem occurs in line 296 `\end\documentclass{beamer}`. The following code looks like an example and won't be showed in the builded pdf file by maxtex.

Comment: I don't see that line at all (and that's a beamer presentation, while your project in this question is a two-column manuscript). If you're having a different problem with another project, please accept this answer by clicking on the "tick" symbol first, and ask a new question. (Or you can contact Overleaf support at support@overleaf.com, if it's an Overleaf-specific issue.)

Comment: Thank you for your help! It's a mistake. It works right now. And I will report it to the organiser using this link!